# How can I move a group along a path?

Tags: bezier-curves, groups

I created a very simple railroad using an *array-modifier* followed by an *curve-modifier*, after that I wanted to run a train on the railroad. The Locomotive is consisting of several grouped objects which can be moved as a whole.

[image]

When a add another curve modifier to the groups parent all other grouped items stay in their previous location.

How could the group be moved along the curve?

[image]

Comment: Chcek this movie (shows how to run train on the rails): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM9Nso_ncEk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have added a curve **modifier** which will 'bend' the object along the curve.

What you want to do, is to go to the **Constraints**-panel and add a **Follow Path** constraint to the parent. From there you can tick **Follow Curve** and press **Animate Path** to make the train drive along the rail.
[image]

Comment: You forgot to explain why the other objects are staying on the initial position: Just parent the other objects to the Locomotive!

Comment: I understood that the objects already had a parent from the question, but I just edited in that the constraint should be added to the parent. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Objects in groups don't move together like in 3D Max. You have to **parent the objects**:

1. **Select all** the objects that need to move together.
2. **Select the parent** (the one guiding the rest) a second time (holding shift).
3. **Ctrl + P -> Set parent to Object** (Keep transformations)

   - Alt + P = Clear parent

The "Keep transformations" part is so the object stays in place (an issue with world / object space).

Comment: They'll move together if you use a [_Group Instance_](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliGroup).