# How to make an object point in the direction that it's going?

Tags: animation

Im making a car animation in blender, and animating it around turns by hand is a real pain. I am wondering if there is a way to make it automatically point in the direction that it is moving?

For example: If I made it turn a corner, then it's front would rotate to continue pointing forward relative to the motion of the car.

Comment: [How can I move a group along a path?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/how-can-i-move-a-group-along-a-path) should help.

Answer (score 6):

You could try using the [*Follow Path*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Relationship/Follow_Path)  constraint.

1. Add a path (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Curve > Path*)
2. Select the object you wish to animate along the path and add a *Follow Path* constraint. Select the curve path as the target:

   [image]
3. You can quickly setup the path animation by pressing *Animate Path*
4. Enable *Follow Curve* to make the object face the direction it is moving in:

   [image]

For more precise animation of the speed along the path, keyframe the *Evaluation time* in *Curve > Path Animation*:

[image]

Note that if you have animated the path by pressing *Animate Path*, you will have to remove the generated *F-modifier* in the *Graph Editor* to be able to keyframe it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use simple `BezierCurve` as a path with `Follow Path` constraint (with `Follow Curve` turned on). Then use `Offset` value to control position along the path.

[image: Follow Path constraint with Follow Curve ticked]

Also if you'd like to make it look like a high speed cornering with a little drift, you might use an Empty as a target for your car, with a little different `Offset` (car would rotate just a little bit before the turn) and `Track To` constraint targeted to the empty leading the way.

[image]

Not an ideal solution, neither physically accurate but might give some ideas how to start off maybe.