# How to change what an object is pointing at

Tags: animation

I'm creating an animation of an airplane and was wondering whether there is a simpler solution to make it pointing at where it is going instead of manually animating it. I found this question: [How to make an object point in the direction that it's going?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/how-to-make-an-object-point-in-the-direction-that-its-going)

The answer suggest using paths, however it is very old and I can neither find the follow path constraint in blender 2.8 nor access the information in the blender wiki link as the page cannot be found. So I chose to ask a new question.

So here's my idea: We have already animated the path. So would it be possible to copy the object's motion to a point object (or any other object that won't be visible in the final render) and off-set it by one frame or so. Then the point will be one frame "in the future". This should work, however I cannot figure out how to change where the airplane is pointing at. Is there such a function in blender and how can it be accessed?

Comment: I recommend investigating the tracking constraints. More specifically, the *Damped Track* constraint, which is the only one (of the track variety, anyway) that seems to work as expected right out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to point an object to another (for example to an empty) you can use an "object constraint" and targeting to the empty.

check this video:

[image]

Comment: perfect! that's exactly what I was looking for.