# Adding Bend Modifier for a parent object and treating as if it's a single object

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, parent, groups

I just learnt how to bend planes into a sphere from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24053/38547). But now I have created curves for few countries just on top of a plane, and **I do not know how to make all of them (plane, curves and meshes on top) bend into a sphere**

---

What I tried:

1) Made all the countries children of the plane [ocean] and applied a modifier to the parent.

[image]
Result: Modifier doesn't apply to children, but only to the plane got bent; Found an [explanation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27744/why-are-modifiers-not-applied-to-child-objects) that modifiers are not intended to be applied on children :(

2) Added two bend modifiers (after a subdivision modifier) for one country and tried applying to all countries using `Ctrl+L` and each country is bending into a globe :/

3) Tried `Alt+Click`, but it doesn't seem to work! Do I need to set the hotkey in the preferences?

**UPDATE**:

4) Lattice Modifier on Parent doesn't work too, sub-objects are not obeying to the stretch and skew of the lattice

[image]

Clearly, the ocean layer is obeying, but the countries continue to stay the same regardless of the lattice's shape

---

So, here's my question: **How do I apply a modifier that would treat the parent object as a single object [as if it was just a plane with countries embedded on it]?**

Comment: I think you should join the countries in one single curve or mesh (not necessarily including the 'ocean' plane)

Comment: @lemon that would completely defeat the purpose of having each country as a separate curve I guess! I need each country to remain as a separate object (or subobject) so I can interact with them accordingly. Is that possible after merging them?

Comment: [this](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?320774-Bending-Curving-Multiple-Objects-Around-a-Single-Point) is what I want, but I don't find proper answers there... :(

Comment: You can use a lattice to do that. Deform the lattice the same way you did for the plane (add the wanted resolution to it). Then add a lattice modifier to the countries (do it on a first one then ctrl+L). I won't have time to write a complete answer before an hour or two...

Comment: @lemon, I tried it, but same results, I can't get the countries [children] obey that - I've updated the answer

Comment: @lemon, any other way to accomplish this? And I found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2498/38547) that object groups in blender doesn't behave the way it does in 3dsmax, does this mean it's easily done in 3ds max?

Comment: With lattice, you'll have to set the modifier on each object (country) using ctrl+L (as you said in 2/), parenting will not do the job. Except if this way of doing it does not correspond to your need, I'll write it as an answer asap

Comment: hurray!, it's bending altogether with the lattice when modifiers are all linked :) now, how do I make that cubic lattice spherical?

Comment: The exact same approach as for the plane (ocean) before. You'll need to set the lattice definition appropriately and play with scaling to adjust the curves

Comment: I think I got the idea, make a lattice with W=1 so it essentially makes it a plane, then use the same idea of 2 empties to make that lattice a sphere! [Was scratching my head tweaking 3D lattice points symmetrically, problem's easy nullyfying a dimension :P]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment, you can use a lattice to do that.

The idea is the following:

- Create a lattice and scale it appropriately (1x2, as for the plane mentioned in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053)). **Scale it in object mode** (edit mode will give a bad result deforming the curves later).
- Give it the resolution you want, ie 20x40x1

[image]

- Bend it using 2 empties

[image]

- Now add your curves, rotate and scale them to fit the same size as the lattice
- Add a lattice modifier to one of the curves
- Then link the modifier to the others <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> then 'modifiers'

[image]

*edit* the blend file:
[image]

Concerning Russia, I think this is due to that:

If you convert it to mesh, lines are going east/west for a long distance, so when bent, that does not work: "these lines are like the string of a bent bow"

[image]

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for that beautiful tutorial! There's one problem with this method though and I can't seem to eliminate it. The rendered meshes have a problem - they aren't simple they are way too complex that it takes so much time to render and a lot of frame drops even in the viewport :(

Comment: Take a look at this [image](http://imgur.com/a/jfe9W). It shows how it looks when a material is applied and lit [ignore the clouds and the water]. And for me Russia was messed up when done like this, I had to add subdivisions to Russia so it renders up without overlaps - but again these subdivisions made it even more complex! Is there a solution for that or atleast a workaround?

Comment: Here's another [one](http://imgur.com/9jbmO1K). Why wouldn't it generate nice clean mesh with few evenly distributed vertices [and wires] as it they were cut out of a circle? Has it got something to do with the SVGs? [Your Russia's messed up too?]

Comment: The link to the image shows nothing... concerning Russia I don't know its probably a straight line somewhere but I did not found it. I'll add the blend file to the answer to allow you to check if they are different.

Comment: Sorry that the first link is dead; I've uploaded all screenshots [here](http://imgur.com/a/KD9oh); Your blender file and mine looks alike and in both Russia is messed up - actually what's there in Russia is in every other country except that we don't get to see them unless they have a material and are lit.

Comment: @ZekeDran, answer updated, about Russia

Comment: Thanks a lot lemon; is there any way to get evenly distributed mesh both horizontally and vertically, so that it's just right? I think this is how blender makes mesh from svg's right? I know its getting bigger should I post a separate question about that?

Comment: @ZekeDran, yes you should ask another question, as I don't know how to do it and/or explain it shortly. The solution may be around converting to mesh but this is not simple from vector graphics.