# SVG Imports: Getting the mesh right

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, wireframe, svg

I imported an SVG, scaled it and rotated it. And all looked clean, until I bent it into a sphere, applied a material onto it to see that the mesh has toooooo many horizontal wires and almost no vertical wires making it unable to bend it vertically.

I followed the instructions  from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78606/38547) [and a lot from the comments :P] Here's a screenshot that explains what I'm talking about:

[image]

**What should I do so that the mesh is clean with evenly distributed wires allowing the 2D structure to bend the right way?**

[image]

I'm expecting in such a way that it would have minimal number of wires allowing it to be bent nicely (just like a 16x16 lattice is bent nicely into a sphere without any random wires)

**EDIT**:

Regarding **Remesh** modifier (answer for the tagged possible duplicate question), it seems it doesn't work well here. Here's what happens when I apply `Remesh` modifier. [It doesn't improve with increase/decrease in Octree Depth or sharpness or threshold]

[image]

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for showing those. I've updated my answer. And Second one's about curving/bending and they suggested using subdivision surfaces if it doesn't bend properly, however for me, i am able to bend it adding subdivision modifier, but I couldn't manage to get  clean mesh